# How do I create Java classes instead of C++ classes in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I created a new project but it only gives me the option to create C++ classes. How do I change that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Click with right on src folder,then Mark Directory As / Source Root.

Comment: I think the correct answer here is to not create an NDK project